# Stereo Vision (OpenCV) - How can I improve my stereo rectification results?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, stereo-3d

I am currently carrying out an undergraduate project where I need to find the depth in a stereo image, thus it is crucial to get a good disparity map. I am carrying out the calibration using the traditional chessboard method, and alternating between using from 20 to 90 views which I believe is more than enough. The rectification though is not coming out well. I am using OpenCV and Python.

These are the rectification results with 20 chessboard views used for calibration.

[image: Rectification Results]

This is my code for the rectification and calibration, also for the main program.

Stereo Cameras Calibration

```
import cv,time,sys
from itertools import izip

n_boards=0  
board_w=int(sys.argv[1])    
board_h=int(sys.argv[2])    
n_boards=int(sys.argv[3])   
board_n=board_w*board_h     
board_sz=(board_w,board_h)  

image_points0=cv.CreateMat(n_boards*board_n,2,cv.CV_32FC1)
object_points=cv.CreateMat(n_boards*board_n,3,cv.CV_32FC1)
point_counts=cv.CreateMat(n_boards,1,cv.CV_32SC1)
intrinsic_matrix0=cv.CreateMat(3,3,cv.CV_32FC1)
distortion_coefficient0=cv.CreateMat(5,1,cv.CV_32FC1)
image_points1=cv.CreateMat(n_boards*board_n,2,cv.CV_32FC1)
intrinsic_matrix1=cv.CreateMat(3,3,cv.CV_32FC1)
distortion_coefficient1=cv.CreateMat(5,1,cv.CV_32FC1)

R=cv.CreateMat(3,3,cv.CV_64F)
T=cv.CreateMat(3,1,cv.CV_64F)
E=cv.CreateMat(3,3,cv.CV_64F)
F=cv.CreateMat(3,3,cv.CV_64F)
#term_crit=(cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,30,0.1)
#capture frames of specified properties and modification of matrix values
i=0
z=0 
successes=0

found=0
with open('Left.txt','rb') as f:
    imgl= [line.strip() for line in f]
    with open('Right.txt','rb') as f1:
         imgr=[line.strip() for line in f1]
         for (image0,image1) in izip(imgl,imgr):
        if image0 =='' or image1== '' :
            break;
        else:

                Image0 = cv.LoadImage(image0)
                Image1 = cv.LoadImage(image1)

            gray_image0=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(Image0),8,1)
            cv.CvtColor(Image0,gray_image0,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
            gray_image1=cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(Image1),8,1)
            cv.CvtColor(Image1,gray_image1,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
            (found0,corners0)=cv.FindChessboardCorners(gray_image0,board_sz,cv.CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH| cv.CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS)
            (found1,corners1)=cv.FindChessboardCorners(gray_image1,board_sz,cv.CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH| cv.CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS)
            cv.FindCornerSubPix(gray_image0,corners0,(11,11),(-1,-1),(cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,30,0.001))
            cv.FindCornerSubPix(gray_image1,corners1,(11,11),(-1,-1),(cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,30,0.001))     
            if found0==1 and found1==1:
                print "found frame number {0}".format(z+1)
                cv.DrawChessboardCorners(Image0,board_sz,corners0,1) 
                cv.DrawChessboardCorners(Image1,board_sz,corners1,1) 
                cv.ShowImage("Left cam corners",Image0);
                cv.ShowImage("Right cam corners",Image1);
                cv.WaitKey(33)
                corner_count0=len(corners0)
                corner_count1=len(corners1)
                print "corner count0",corner_count0
                print "corner count1",corner_count1
                z=z+1

            if len(corners0)==board_n and len(corners1)==board_n:
                step=successes*board_n
                k=step
                for j in range(board_n):
                    cv.Set2D(image_points0,k,0,corners0[j][0])
                    cv.Set2D(image_points0,k,1,corners0[j][1])

                    cv.Set2D(image_points1,k,0,corners1[j][0])
                    cv.Set2D(image_points1,k,1,corners1[j][1])

                    cv.Set2D(object_points,k,0,float(j)/float(board_w))
                    cv.Set2D(object_points,k,1,float(j)%float(board_w))
                    cv.Set2D(object_points,k,2,0.0)

                    k=k+1
                    cv.Set2D(point_counts,successes,0,board_n)
            successes=successes+1
            print successes
            time.sleep(2)
            print "-------------------------------------------------"
            print "\n"
print "Calibration OK, Matrices Created"
cv.DestroyWindow("Test Frame")

# now assigning new matrices according to view_count
object_points2=cv.CreateMat(successes*board_n,3,cv.CV_32FC1)
image_points20=cv.CreateMat(successes*board_n,2,cv.CV_32FC1)
image_points21=cv.CreateMat(successes*board_n,2,cv.CV_32FC1)
point_counts2=cv.CreateMat(successes,1,cv.CV_32SC1)

for i in range(successes*board_n):
    cv.Set2D(image_points20,i,0,cv.Get2D(image_points0,i,0))
    cv.Set2D(image_points20,i,1,cv.Get2D(image_points0,i,1))

    cv.Set2D(image_points21,i,0,cv.Get2D(image_points1,i,0))
    cv.Set2D(image_points21,i,1,cv.Get2D(image_points1,i,1))

    cv.Set2D(object_points2,i,0,cv.Get2D(object_points,i,0))
    cv.Set2D(object_points2,i,1,cv.Get2D(object_points,i,1))
    cv.Set2D(object_points2,i,2,cv.Get2D(object_points,i,2))


for i in range(successes):
    cv.Set2D(point_counts2,i,0,cv.Get2D(point_counts,i,0))

cv.Set2D(intrinsic_matrix0,0,0,1.0)
cv.Set2D(intrinsic_matrix0,1,1,1.0)

cv.Set2D(intrinsic_matrix1,0,0,1.0)
cv.Set2D(intrinsic_matrix1,1,1,1.0)

print "Checking Camera Calibration"
# camera calibration
cv.StereoCalibrate(object_points2,image_points20,image_points21,point_counts2,intrinsic_matrix0,
distortion_coefficient0,intrinsic_matrix1,distortion_coefficient1,cv.GetSize(Image0),R,T,E,F,
(cv.CV_TERMCRIT_ITER+cv.CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 30, 1e-6), (cv.CV_CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH+cv.CV_CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST+cv.CV_CALIB_FIX_FOCAL_LENGTH ))
print "Calibration Successful"  

# storing results in xml files
cv.Save("Image points1.xml",image_points20)
cv.Save("Image points2.xml",image_points21)
cv.Save("Intrinsics0.xml",intrinsic_matrix0)
cv.Save("Distortion0.xml",distortion_coefficient0)

cv.Save("Intrinsics1.xml",intrinsic_matrix1)
cv.Save("Distortion1.xml",distortion_coefficient1)
cv.Save("R.xml",R)
cv.Save("T.xml",T)
```

Stereo Rectification

```
import cv
import time
import numpy as np

def stereorectify(image0,image1):   

# Loading matrices output from the calibration step
    intrinsic0=cv.Load("Intrinsics0.xml")
    distortion0=cv.Load("Distortion0.xml")
    intrinsic1=cv.Load("Intrinsics1.xml")
    distortion1=cv.Load("Distortion1.xml")
    R=cv.Load("R.xml")
    T=cv.Load("T.xml")

# Rectification
    Ro=cv.CreateMat(3,1,cv.CV_64F);
    cv.Rodrigues2(R, Ro)
    size=cv.GetSize(image0)
    R1=cv.CreateMat(3,3,cv.CV_64F)
    R2=cv.CreateMat(3,3,cv.CV_64F)
    P1=cv.CreateMat(3,4,cv.CV_64F)
    P2=cv.CreateMat(3,4,cv.CV_64F)
    Q=cv.CreateMat(4,4,cv.CV_64F)
    flags=cv.CV_CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY
    cv.StereoRectify(intrinsic0, intrinsic1, distortion0,distortion1,(320,240),R,T,R2, R1, P1,P2, Q,0,0)

#print newImageSize
    map1x = cv.CreateImage(size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F,1)
    map2x = cv.CreateImage(size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F,1)
#Right maps
    map1y = cv.CreateImage(size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F,1)
    map2y = cv.CreateImage(size, cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F,1)

# Undistorting/ Rectification
    cv.InitUndistortRectifyMap(intrinsic0, distortion0, R1, intrinsic0, map1x, map1y)
    cv.InitUndistortRectifyMap(intrinsic1, distortion1, R2, intrinsic1,map2x, map2y)
    cv.InitUndistortRectifyMap(intrinsic0, distortion0, R1, intrinsic0, map1x, map1y)
    cv.InitUndistortRectifyMap(intrinsic1, distortion1, R2, intrinsic1,map2x, map2y)
    cv.Remap(image0,image0, map1x, map1y,cv.CV_INTER_CUBIC)
    cv.Remap(image1,image1, map2x, map2y,cv.CV_INTER_CUBIC)

    cv.Save("R1.xml",R1);
    cv.Save("map1x.xml",map1x);
    cv.Save("Q.xml",Q)
    return image0,image1
```

Main Program

```
import cv2,cv
from Disparity import getDisparity
from dimensions import dimensions
from stereo_rectify_live import stereorectify
import numpy as np
print "begin"
# setup webcam
capture1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1);# Camera 1 capture
capture2 = cv2.VideoCapture(0);# Camera 2 capture
# set resolution
capture1.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320)
capture1.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240)

capture2.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320)
capture2.set(cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240)

h,w=240,320
Q=cv.Load("Q.xml");
Q=np.array(Q,np.float32);
f=0.8*w
#Q = np.float32([[1, 0, 0, -0.5*w],
#               [0,-1, 0,  0.5*h],
#               [0, 0, 0,     -f], 
#               [0, 0, 1,      0]])
xyz=cv.CreateImage((240,320),cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F,3)
z=cv.CreateMat(240,320,cv.CV_32FC1)
fromto=[(2,0)]
print "begin"
i=0;npts=0;dist=0;k = 0;
while k<100:
    # Setting up queries
        ret,cam1=capture1.read()
        print ret
        ret,cam2=capture2.read()
        print ret
        cam1,cam2=stereorectify(cv.fromarray(cam1),cv.fromarray(cam2))
        cam1 = np.array(cam1);
        cam2 = np.array(cam2);
        cv2.imshow('First Camera',cam1);
        cv2.imshow('Second Camera',cam2);
        disparity = getDisparity(cam1, cam2, "BM")
        cv2.imshow("Disparity",np.array(disparity))
        first = cv2.inRange(np.array(disparity),np.array(220),np.array(255))
        xyz = cv2.reprojectImageTo3D(first,Q)
        cv.MixChannels([cv.fromarray(xyz)],[z],fromto)
        focal_length = Q[2,3];
        base_distance = 7.112; #in cms
        x,y,w1,h1=dimensions(cv2.cvtColor(np.array(disparity),cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR),1,170,240);
        temp = np.array(z[x:y+h,y:x+w]);
        t=temp[temp != -np.inf];
        disparity = np.mean(abs(t));
        print 'shape',np.shape(z[x:y+h,y:x+w]),np.shape(temp);
        Actualdist = focal_length * base_distance/disparity;
        print 'disparity',disparity
        print 'f', focal_length
        print "Actual Distance (in cms) from object =",Actualdist
        print k
        cv2.waitKey(10);
        k=k+1;


print "done!"
```

Would greatly appreciate any help on this matter as I feel stuck on what I could do to improve my results. Thanks!!

Comment: You could start by pinning down some possible explanations by debugging your code. The questions shouldn't be of a "Here's my full code, what's wrong with it?" type.

Split your code into parts, learn what they should do and go through it step by step checking which part is not working correctly.

Comment: I tried changing the criteria and flags of the stereocalibrate method, which yielded better results in rectification, but still not up to standard.